# MongoDB: sort by in list

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have event members list

```
[
  {"user":"id1", "event":"..."},
  {"user":"id2", "event":"..."},
  {"user":"id3", "event":"..."}
]
```

And friends id list

```
["id2","id3"]
```

How I can sort all event members by friends id list?

```
[
  {"user":"id2", "event":"..."},
  {"user":"id3", "event":"..."},
  {"user":"id1", "event":"..."}
]
```

PS: I need keep functions $skip and $limit

Comment: I think you are mixing concepts here. You actually want to _find_ the friends in that list, and then you want to sort them by friend id, right?

Comment: I want to find everyone who comes to the event, and if there are friends, then show the top of the list. I need paging

Comment: I am not aware of a possibility to do this in a query. I'd do that programmatically.